# TFS-Powershell Scripting

Tags: powershell, encoding

I have this script which runs fine with no issue on the server locally but when I made a task in Team Foundation Server(update2017) and run it from there it throws an error, the error is after the script for reference.

```
 param(
 [string]$ServiceNames
)
if([string]::IsNullOrWhiteSpace($ServiceNames))
{
   throw "Missing argument [-ServiceNames $ServiceNames]"
}
    $Services=$ServiceNames.Split(",")
    foreach($Service in $Services)
{
   if(Get-Service $Service | Where {$_.status –eq 'Stopped'})
{
   Get-Service $Service | Where {$_.status –eq 'Stopped'} | Start-Service
   Write-Host "$Service has been started."
}
else
{
   Write-Host "$Service is already running."
}
}
```

and this error came.

```
if(Get-Service $Service | Where {$_.status â?"eq 'Stopped'})
```

> Unexpected token 'â?"eq 'Stopped'})

Thanks in advance.

Comment: This is an encoding issue.  Is your script saved in UTF8-BOM?

Comment: I am not sure but in case if it's not how to do that?

Comment: Are you using an editor to write the script?  VSCode perhaps?  If so, you should be able to save it with a certain encoding.

Comment: No, I am using Windows powershell ISE.

Comment: Sorry, the ISE is deprecated and limited.  I don't see a way to change the encoding from it.  I'd advise you to move to VSCode with the PowerShell extension as that's MSFT's direction for creating powershell scripts.  From there, you can update a file's encoding in the bottom right.  You'll want to convert the file to UTF8 with BOM.  **Also, you're using long-dashes instead of short in `-eq`, which is the cause of your encoding issue (charcode 8211 vs charcode 45)**.  Did you copy/paste this code from an email or something that auto-converts dashes?

Comment: TheIncorrigible is probably right (if you look very close, you will notice that the minus in front `-ServiceNames` in not the same length as the one in front of `–eq`). Anyways, to resolve the issue: I would just remove the minus sign(s) and retype them.

Comment: As an extra piece of information, Windows PowerShell's engine parses everything as "ANSI" unless it's encoded as "UTF8 with BOM".

Comment: Another extra piece of information: Microsoft Office packages (as **Word** and **Outlook**) tend to automatically change dashes (from charcode 45 to 8211) around phrases. I recommend to avoid these applications for copying PowerShell scripts (or at least use them with care).

Comment: Thanks @TheIncorrigible1., the script is working fine now.

Comment: Thanks @iRon for all the suggestions.

Comment: @AbhishekM, If this issue has been resolved, you could share your solution as an answer, and then mark/accept it as the answer, so it could help other community members who get the same issue as yours.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, copy/Paste from Word or Outlook always inserts characters you don't want in the editor. For that i have put below function in my Powershell profile file.

This is not meant as a direct answer to this question because [TheIncorrigible1](https://stackoverflow.com/users/8188846/theincorrigible1) already gave that. 
It may however help others.

```
function Editor-ReplaceSmartQuotes {
    ## this function replaces "smart-qoutes" and long dashes you get 
    ## when pasting from Word into normal straight characters (" ' -)
    $text = Editor-GetSelectedText
    $psISE.CurrentFile.Editor.InsertText(($text -creplace '[\u201C\u201D\u201E\u201F\u2033\u2036]', '"' `
                                                -creplace "[\u2018\u2019\u201A\u201B\u2032\u2035]", "'" `
                                                -creplace "[\u2013\u2014\u2015]", "-"))
}
```

and added it to my ISE menu with:

```
Editor-AddMenu "Replace Smart_Quotes in Selection" {Editor-ReplaceSmartQuotes} "Alt+Q"
```