# Powershell only errors out when i run the .ps1 file

Tags: powershell

I am running this script below and when i execute inside of powershell it runs and provides the exact link I am requesting. When I save in a ps1 file and call the file I get this error. Why would it run fine in powershell but not in the actual file?

My code:

```
$year = $date.year
$date = GET-DATE 
$datemonth=$date.month
$month = (Get-Culture).DateTimeFormat.GetMonthName($datemonth)
$url = 'https://health.mil/Reference-Center/Technical-Documents?query=DMIS'
$links=((Invoke-WebRequest –Uri $url).Links | Where-Object {($_.innerHTML - 
like "*DMIS ID Monthly*") -and ($_.innerHTML -notlike "*Change*") -and 
($_.innerHTML -like "*$month*")}).href
$links
```

The error:

At C:\Users\Documents\DMIS\web_scrape2.ps1:6 char:178
+ ... HTML -notlike "*Change*") -and ($_.innerHTML -like "*$month*")}).href
+                                                                 ~~~~~~~~~
The string is missing the terminator: ".
At C:\User\Documents\DMIS\web_scrape2.ps1:8 char:1
+
Missing closing ')' in expression.
    + CategoryInfo          : ParserError: (:) [], ParentContainsErrorRecordException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : TerminatorExpectedAtEndOfString

Comment: is this exactly what your ps1 file looks like? even the line breaks

Comment: @missy - your code shows "smart quotes" - the curved/curled quotes. PoSh has a known problem with those. replace them with the straight versions and things will likely work fine.

Comment: no there is no spaces in the code...stack overflow formatted it that way. Removed the " and replaced with single ' and different error.

Comment: paste new errorl. This runs fine for me in ps1 form

Comment: At C:\Users\mhoward1\Documents\DMIS\web_scrape2.ps1:6 char:30
+ ... ebRequest â€“Uri $url).Links | Where-Object {($_.innerHTML -like '*DM ...
+                 ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
The string is missing the terminator: ".
At C:\Users\mhoward1\Documents\DMIS\web_scrape2.ps1:8 char:1
+
Missing closing ')' in expression.
   + CategoryInfo          : ParserError: (:) [], ParseException
   + FullyQualifiedErrorId : TerminatorExpectedAtEndOfString

Comment: lol i mean in post and i see you updated your post please dont paste code in comments

Comment: There still appears to be "smart" quotes in `-like “*DMIS ID Monthly*”)`. Change these to a plain QUOTATION MARK.

Comment: Also, place `$date = GET-DATE` on top of the script so the line that appears to be the first `$year = $date.year` will actually get the year value for the current date.

Comment: To replace 'smart quotes' into straight ones, you could use [this function of mine](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51288442/tfs-powershell-scripting#51291881) and place it in your PowerShell profile.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on the problem description and the original form or your question, it sounds like you have a *character-encoding problem*.

**Your code contains *non-ASCII-range* Unicode quotation marks_** - (LEFT DOUBLE QUOTATION MARK, [`U+201c`](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/201c/index.htm) and RIGHT DOUBLE QUOTATION MARK, [`U+201d`](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/201d/index.htm)) and **punctuation** (EN DASH [`U+2013`](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/2013/index.htm)) - **which PowerShell recognizes *in principle*** as their ASCII counterparts, but **only if it interprets the *character encoding* of the input file correctly.**

Be sure to **save your script as *UTF-8 with BOM*** in order for Windows PowerShell to recognize these characters correctly.
(PowerShell *Core* would recognize them correctly if UTF-8-encoded even without a BOM).

Answer (score 0):

From the Unicode standard at https://www.unicode.org/charts/PDF/U0000.pdf

The code is using the "preferred characters in English for paired quotation marks."

```
0022 " QUOTATION MARK
• neutral (vertical), used as opening or closing
quotation mark
• preferred characters in English for paired
quotation marks are 201C “  & 201D ”
```

**Update:**

When I run this code, here are the results. Is this correct?

```
PS H:\src\tws> Get-Content .\t.ps1
$year = $date.year
$date = GET-DATE
$datemonth=$date.month
$month = (Get-Culture).DateTimeFormat.GetMonthName($datemonth)
$url = 'https://health.mil/Reference-Center/Technical-Documents?query=DMIS'

$links = ((Invoke-WebRequest –Uri $url).Links |
    Where-Object {
        ($_.innerHTML -like "*DMIS ID Monthly*") -and
        ($_.innerHTML -notlike "*Change*") -and
        ($_.innerHTML -like "*$month*")
    }).href

$links

PS H:\src\tws> .\t.ps1
/Reference-Center/Technical-Documents/2018/09/27/DMIS-ID-Monthly-October-2018
```

Comment: also....now when i remove the " and I run in powershel,l I no longer get the link result...but when i add the " back in the where-object clause I get a the link result. Mind you this is outside of the file this is directly in powershell

Comment: Have you changed `“*DMIS ID Monthly*”` to `"*DMIS ID Monthly*"`?

Comment: I tried both and still get error in the .ps1 file but both types of double quotes return link directly in powershell. The single quote will not return a link.

Comment: Please edit the question to paste in the current code and error message. The current code in the question still shows smart quotes.

Comment: Yes that is the correct result. But when i run that using my file i still get the error.